# Proving that $\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2} \geq \frac{8}{(a+b)^2}$ for $a,b>0$

Tags: inequality

I found something that I'm not quite sure about when trying to prove this inequality.

I've proven that

$$\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\geq \dfrac{4}{a+b}$$

already. My idea now is to replace $a$ with $a^2$ and $b^2$, so we now have

$$\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}\geq \dfrac{4}{a^2+b^2}$$

So to prove the required result, we just need to show that

$$\dfrac{4}{a^2+b^2} \geq \dfrac{8}{(a+b)^2}$$

or equivalently

$$(a+b)^2 \geq 2(a^2+b^2)$$

But this inequality cannot be true since the pair $(a,b)=(1,2)$ doesn't work. If anything, the reverse is always true!

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Also, some help with formatting would be greatly appreciated. The current format hurts my poor eyes. Could somebody please centre the equations?

Comment: Please fix the title, too, $x$ and $y$ have nothing to do with $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Centred! Note, Enclosing text between \$\$  \$\$ does the centering and puts you in display style maths mode.

Comment: You are trying to prove a sharpening of the inequality in your first formula, not a consequence. How did you prove that result? Maybe a modification works here.

Comment: I proved the first formula by starting with $(a+b)^2\geq 4ab$ and manipulating that. Regarding what you said about sharpening the formula, does this mean that it is impossible to attempt to solve the required result using what I've done? Also, how did you know that it was a sharpening, and not a consequence?

Comment: Hint: You have the situation $$\frac1{a^2}+\frac1{b^2} \ge  \frac8{(a+b)^2} \ge \frac4{a^2+b^2}$$  Do you see why your approach failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have already proved the inequality.

Here, I will answer the following question.

> What have I done wrong here?

First, there is nothing wrong in the following part.

> I've proven that
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\geq \dfrac{4}{a+b}$$
>
> already. My idea now is to replace $a$ with $a^2$ and $b^2$, so we now have
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}\geq \dfrac{4}{a^2+b^2}$$
>
> So to prove the required result, we just need to show that
>
> $$\dfrac{4}{a^2+b^2} \geq \dfrac{8}{(a+b)^2}$$
>
> or equivalently
>
> $$(a+b)^2 \geq 2(a^2+b^2)$$

Here, note that what we can say is that **if
$$(a+b)^2 \geq 2(a^2+b^2)$$
is true for $a\gt 0,b\gt 0$,** then we know that the inequality is true.

By the way, as you wrote,

> But this inequality cannot be true since the pair $(a,b)=(1,2)$ doesn't work.

Now, all we can say is that
$$(a+b)^2 \geq 2(a^2+b^2)$$
is not true.

Hence, we can say nothing about the inequality. (You need to seek another way as others showed.)

It seems that you are misunderstanding something because you are saying

> If anything, the reverse is always true!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is simple enough that you can just be mechanical about it
$$
\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\geq\frac{8}{(a+b)^2}\iff(a^2+b^2)(a+b)^2-8a^2b^2\geq0.
$$
The claim now follows because
$$
(a^2+b^2)(a+b)^2-8a^2b^2=(a-b)^2(a^2+4ab+b^2)\geq0,\quad a,b>0.
$$

Comment: I've already proven the result using the same method, which as you've shown works out quite nicely if we use the classic "Throw everything to one side" method. However, my question is moreso aimed towards identifying the error in the method I've provided above, when everything seems legitimate.

Comment: @Trogdor You didn't make an error. It's just that the method you attempted (proving this new inequality based on a previous one) wouldn't work in this particular problem. You yourself gave a numerical example to illustrate this.

Comment: @Trogdor Another way to put this is: you have proved some result $A$ and now you have to prove $B$. You (correctly) realize that *if* $A\implies B$ then you're done. But then you checked whether $A\implies B$ was true and you (correctly again) found that it wasn't the case. So now you can either find some true $A'$ and prove $A'\implies B$ or you can prove $B$ directly. Math110 and chenbai did the former (e.g. Math110's $A'$ is the Holder's inequality) and I did the latter.

Answer (score 4):

$\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2} \ge \dfrac{2}{ab} \ge \dfrac{8}{(a+b)^2} \iff (a+b)^2 \ge 4ab$

Answer (score 3):

Use Holder
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}\right)(a+b)(a+b)\ge (1+1)^3=8$$

Answer (score 1):

It's a particular case of the *power means inequality*: the $p$-*th power mean* of $n$ positive real numbers $a_1,\dots, a_n$ is:
$$M_p(a_1,\dots,a_n)=\biggl(\frac{a_1^p+\dots+a_n^p}n\biggr)^{\!\tfrac1p}.$$
It can be proved that if $p<q$, then $M_p(a_1,\dots,a_n)\le M_q(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, and we have equality if and only if $a_1=\dots=a_n$.

Now the arithmetic mean of $a$ and $b$ is $M_1(a,b)$, and by the above we have the inequality: $\,M_{-2}(a,b)\le  M_1(a,b)$, which is equivalent to $\,M_{-2}(a,b)^2\le  M_1(a,b)^2$, or
$$\frac1{M_{-2}(a,b)^2}=\frac12\biggl(\frac1{a^2}+\frac1{b^2}\biggr)\ge\frac1{M_1(a,b)^2}=\biggl(\frac 2{a+b}\bigg)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $a,b>0$, let
\begin{equation}
A(a,b)=\frac{a+b}{2}, \quad G(a,b)=\sqrt{ab}\,, \quad H(a,b)=\frac{2}{\dfrac1{a}+\dfrac1{b}}
\end{equation}
are respectively the arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic means of two positive numbers $a,b$.

It is commom knowledge that
\begin{equation}
A(a,b)\ge G(a,b) \quad\text{and}\quad H(a,b)=\frac{G^2(a,b)}{A(a,b)}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, we derive
\begin{equation}
A\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)\ge G\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)=G^2(a,b)
\Longleftrightarrow 1\ge\frac{G^2(a,b)}{A\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
A^2(a,b)\ge G^2(a,b).
\end{equation}
Consequently,  we deduce
\begin{equation}
A^2(a,b)\ge G^2(a,b)\frac{G^2(a,b)}{A\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)}
=\frac{G^2\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)}{A\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)}
=H\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)
\end{equation}
which can be reformulated as
\begin{equation}
\biggl(\frac{a+b}{2}\biggr)^2\ge\frac{2}{\dfrac1{a^2}+\dfrac1{b^2}}
\Longleftrightarrow
\dfrac1{a^2}+\dfrac1{b^2}\ge\frac{8}{(a+b)^2}.
\end{equation}