# Prove that $\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2} \geq \frac{8}{(a+b)^2}$ for $a,b > 0$

Tags: inequality

I've assumed that it must be related to Harmonic Mean and I rewrote it as $\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}} \leq \frac{(a+b)^2}{4}$ but I have no idea what to do further. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: [RMS-HM](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality).

Comment: Not true if either one of $a$ or $b$ is negative. We must assume $a,b > 0$. Otherwise, I can make the RHS arbitrarily large, with the LHS being finite.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2} \geq \frac{8}{(a+b)^2}$ for $a,b>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340034/proving-that-frac1a2-frac1b2-geq-frac8ab2-for-a-b0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need for fancy machinery, this follows directly from the AM-GM inequality. Let me show you how. I believe you are assuming $a,b > 0$.

$$a^2 + b^2 \ge 2ab \quad\quad (1)$$
follows from AM-GM inequality applied to $a^2$ and $b^2$. Adding $2ab$ to both sides, we have $$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \ge 4ab \quad\quad (2)$$
Multiply inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get,
$$(a+b)^2 (a^2 + b^2) \ge 8a^2b^2$$
which is just $$\boxed{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2} \geq \frac{8}{(a+b)^2}}$$

---

**Note:** $a,b> 0$ is required. If either one of $a$ or $b$ is negative, I can make the RHS arbitrarily large, with the LHS being finite. In particular, take $a = 1$ and $b = -1 + \epsilon$. Make $\epsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $a,b>0$, let
\begin{equation}
A(a,b)=\frac{a+b}{2}, \quad G(a,b)=\sqrt{ab}\,, \quad H(a,b)=\frac{2}{\dfrac1{a}+\dfrac1{b}}
\end{equation}
are respectively the arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic means of two positive numbers $a,b$.

It is commom knowledge that
\begin{equation}
A(a,b)\ge G(a,b) \quad\text{and}\quad H(a,b)=\frac{G^2(a,b)}{A(a,b)}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, we derive
\begin{equation}
A\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)\ge G\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)=G^2(a,b)
\Longleftrightarrow 1\ge\frac{G^2(a,b)}{A\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
A^2(a,b)\ge G^2(a,b).
\end{equation}
Consequently,  we deduce
\begin{equation}
A^2(a,b)\ge G^2(a,b)\frac{G^2(a,b)}{A\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)}
=\frac{G^2\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)}{A\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)}
=H\bigl(a^2,b^2\bigr)
\end{equation}
which can be reformulated as
\begin{equation}
\biggl(\frac{a+b}{2}\biggr)^2\ge\frac{2}{\dfrac1{a^2}+\dfrac1{b^2}}
\Longleftrightarrow
\dfrac1{a^2}+\dfrac1{b^2}\ge\frac{8}{(a+b)^2}.
\end{equation}